# Shower still leaking with epoxy grout

Tags: shower, epoxy, leaking, weep-hole

I redid my shower with Starlike EVO grout. It's a corner stall shower with tile on two walls, a shower enclosure on the other two, and a fiberglass pan with two weep holes.

The shower is leaking on only one side, through the floor into the room below. I've tried using silicone along the bottom edge of the tile, where it meets the pan - plugging and un plugging the weep hole. Nothing seems to solve the problem.

Epoxy grout is completely waterproof... how can any water be leaking through?

Comment: Are you certain it's the tile leaking and not the shower faucet?

Comment: Most times water will flow/drop straight down if nothing is in the way.  If something is in the way, water can flow sideways for a bit before dropping down.  One reason roof leaks can be hard to find from above the roof.

Comment: Can you run the shower without it spraying on the tile? That will eliminate the floor drain and shower faucet as possible causes. Maybe post a photo, someone here may see a problem that your words don't show.

Comment: Just pour a 5-gallon bucket of water into the shower pan without turning the shower on at all. If you get a leak below, it's from the pan/drain. If you don't, then the leak is through the tile or from the supply side plumbing.

Comment: What sort of shower control does it have? Can you remove the escutcheon and see the valve body? That might let you see if it is leaking. (Symmons Temptrol, a common valve here, use an o-ring on the volume control that hardens and leaks over time, into the wall behind the tile where you can’t see it)